# How to "migrate" a free developer iOS app to a paid account?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I created a simple iOS app for myself using the free Apple developer account. I now have a paid developer account.

How do I migrate my existing app with my old free account to the new paid one or does this happen automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If these two developer accounts are registered with different Apple IDs, you'll need to transfer the app. If you upgraded the free developer account to a paid one (with one Apple ID), you do not need to transfer.

To tell if your apps are migrated automatically, you can log into the [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com) with your paid developer account and see if your apps are there. If they are, then you do not need to transfer. If the apps are in AppStoreConnect for paid account page but not free account, you need to transfer.

If you need to, you can transfer by following the steps in [this](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved688524f) Apple developer help page. By transferring the app, you'll keep your existing bundle ID, App Apple ID, and other information.

The button is located in AppStoreConnect app page, at the Additional Information section.